# Javascript select a random object set from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, kineticjs

"Working" example is here (this script deals with the triangle animation)

http://movable.pagodabox.com/

full code here: http://pastebin.com/rgPNxHgJ

This question is mainly about the proper syntax. I have the following:

```
shape.transitionTo({
     offset: {
          x: 10,
          y: 10
     }
})
```

What I want to do is have "x" and "y" be randomly selected from an array, for example:

```
    movementIn = [
        {x: 34, y: 66},
        {x: -34, y: -66}
    ],

    shape.transitionTo({
        offset: movementIn[Math.floor(Math.random() * movementIn.length)],
    });
```

But this doesn't seem to be working... it seems to be only choosing the first item every time. Am I doing something wrong here?

how do I select a random X and Y pair and insert it into the "offset" parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: Syntax looks correct ... maybe the problem is you're initializing the value rather than getting a new value every time?  Hard to tell without the context.

Comment: The `],` looks out of place (in both places, a syntax error in one and a semantic error in the other). Please paste a [minimal] test-case on jsfiddle [focusing on the specific question] and the *exact* code being used ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Works for me"](http://jsfiddle.net/BpdFa/)

```
arr = ["a","b","c"]
res = ""
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   res += arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
}
alert(res)
```

Do note that this is not the "correct" way to pick one item as the distribution is slightly skewed ..

There are some *syntax* and *semantical* issues with the code in the question that should be explored:

```
{
   although_SomeBrowsers: "accept me",
   iAmAnInvalidLiteral: "BecauseThereIsAnExtraComma",
}
```

---

I feel trolled, here you go:

```
arr = [{x:1,y:-1},{x:2,y:-2},{x:3,y:-3}]
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   AN_OBJECT = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
   // do whatever you want to do with what AN_OBJECT names
   alert("x: " + AN_OBJECT.x + " y: " + AN_OBJECT.y)
}
```

Comment: Thanks pst, but this isn't the same... in my array, there are two pairs, where each array item is an X and Y pair... I just think I'm not doing it quite right!

Comment: @j-man86 It is exactly the same. It doesn't matter what *object* is selected; there is still a singular object selected. Change `res = ""` to `res = []` and `res +=` to `res.push` and then you have an array of your arbitrary object. My point is the code posted *Works Here*, insofar as the errors in it are fixed. The idea is correct.

Comment: Maybe im not asking the right question: how do I select a random X and Y pair and insert it into the "offset" parameter?